# What is flag weight?

Tags: support, site-attributes

I noticed this today on my user page:

```
20117
reputation
556 views
flag weight 180
```

What is flag weight? I mean, I have an understanding of what it *should* be, but why would certain flags be more meaningful than others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base flag rating is 100. You get +10 rating for a flag the mods did something about, and -10 for an invalid flagging. Basically, mods will look at your flags first, and a lower flagger rating after. Anything around 100 won't be displayed. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74969/is-there-a-way-to-see-our-flagger-rating/80197#80197)

At 0 weight moderators stop seeing your flags.
At 500 weight you get a badge, then start gaining less and less weight for every valid flag you cast, asymptotically approaching 750.

Comment: Although you can't actually reach 750.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: My life's aspiration crushed.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84300/flag-weight-750-reached Ha! Dreams revived.

Comment: @StuartPegg: I noticed that too. There's still no official word on whether it's a bug or not though.